# How to invert an SVG image?

Tags: linux, command-line, svg, image-processing, vector-graphics

I’m searching for a solution (in Linux console) which “inverts” an SVG. It shall take an input `.svg` and generate output `.svg` with multiple shapes, each one filling a single transparent area. And vice versa - the shapes from the input file shall be converted into transparent regions.

I’ll need to feed the output `.svg` in a 3D CAD environment. So if the original `.svg` is a circle (and importing it in CAD and extruding results in a cylinder), the new, inverted `.svg` shall result in the CAD in a block with cylindrical hole in it.

Comment: It may be easier to use the SVG as-is and subtract the result from an arbitrary block. Cannot your CAD program do this?

Comment: It can, but I wanted to automate it as easy as possible. 
And I was surprised that inverting an svg is so complicated when I searched on the topic last week.

Comment: you'll have to create a script which parses the XML, based on this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55582885/how-to-invert-alpha-channel-of-svg     It depends a lot on how simple or complicated your svg is

Comment: ``convert in.svg -channel RGB -negate /tmp/out.svg''

Comment: @Petepf convert didn’t work for me, resulted in a corrupted file

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to make use of the linux compatible [OpenSCAD](https://openscad.org/) program, which supports [command line use](https://files.openscad.org/documentation/manual/Using_OpenSCAD_in_a_command_line_environment.html). In the example you've provided, you would create an OpenSCAD file containing the import command of your SVG file, along with a linear extrude command. Executing this from command line would result in a cylinder if the SVG file was a circle.

For the inverse, it would be a combination of a cube() command along with a difference() command containing the code which creates a cylinder.

In the GUI for OpenSCAD, this creation is trivial, but necessary. It can be performed in a simple text editor or created as a text file *.SCAD, which when called by the command line, would output what you describe in the question.